# Spring cloud contract jwt token

Tags: spring-security-oauth2, spring-cloud-contract

I'm using spring cloud contracts to generate contract test on producer side. The producer is a resource server protected with oauth2 jwt token.
When I run the test it fails with 401 http error.

In the conract I specify this

```
headers:
Authorization: Bearer some.jwt.token
```

When I generate test I have this

```
WebTestClientRequestSpecification request = given()
                .header("Authorization", "Bearer some.jwt.token")
```

This is my base contract class

```
 @BeforeEach
public void setup() {

    RestAssuredWebTestClient.applicationContextSetup(applicationContext);
    RestAssuredWebTestClient.webTestClient(webTestClient
            .mutateWith(mockJwt().jwt(jwt -> jwt.claim("test", "prova"))));
}
```

If I manually remove the header from generated test it works well, but this configuration override the one specified in "mutateWith()".
Is there a way to say to contract to ignore header in order do remove it in the generated code?
Otherwise, can I specify a mock jwt in contracts?